# What is the fastest way to read and change the first 8 bytes of a file in C++?

Tags: c++, fread, fseek

What is the fastest way to read and change the first 8 bytes of a file in C++?
I don't want to store the whole file in memory, because if I want to edit the first 8 bytes of a 10GB file the program would be very slow, and is very memory inefficient. Is there a way to first read and then change the first n bytes of a file, without opening the file in memory?

Comment: "*without opening the file in memory*" What do you mean by that? Opening the file doesn't do it "in memory"; it just opens the file.

Comment: Opening the file does not entail loading it in memory. You obtain a handle to the file and use it to read as much as you want from the file, i. e. 8 bytes

Comment: I mean that I don't want to read the file into memory, for larger files that would take a long time. I want the same speed for small and large files. Is it possible to edit the first 8 bytes of a large file, with the same speed of a small file? So what is the fastest way to edit the first 8 bytes of a file?

Comment: @DanieldeVogel: What's wrong with the obvious method of just reading 8 bytes, moving back to the start, and writing 8 bytes?

Comment: How do I read and write the first 8 bytes of a file? I tried several methods but none of them worked. Can you share some small example code?

Comment: What methods did you try? The common ones should work. If they didn't, then there's something going on with your system. The likely explanation is that you're not using the methods correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain what you want using `std::fstream`. Example using this would be:

For text-files only:

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::fstream s("test.txt");

    // read the data
    char buff[8+1]{0};
    s.read(buff, 8);
    std::cout << "Data was: " << buff << '\n';

    // handle case when reading reached EOF
    if (!s) {
        std::cout << "only " << s.gcount() << " could be read\n";
        // clear the EOF bit
        s.clear();
    }
    // back to beginning
    s.seekp(0, std::ios_base::beg);

    // overwrite the data
    char data[] = "abcdabcd";
    s.write(data, sizeof data);
}
```

For binary files:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {
    // need to pass additional flags
    std::fstream s("test.mp4", std::ios_base::binary | std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::out);

    char buff[8 + 1] = {0};
    s.read(buff, 8);
    std::cout << "Data was: ";
    for (auto i(0); i < s.gcount(); ++i) {
        std::cout << '[';
        std::cout << std::hex << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << (0xFF & buff[i]);
        std::cout << ']';
    }

    // handle case when reading reached EOF
    if (!s) {
        std::cout << "only " << s.gcount() << " could be read.";
        s.clear();
    }

    // back to beginning
    s.seekp(0, std::ios_base::beg);

    char data[] = {0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08};
    s.write(data, sizeof data);
}
```

Comment: OP wants to read the first 8 bytes as well. (Presumably) before writing.

Comment: @John right, didn't notice that. I corrected my example snippet.

Comment: Thanks! The read works but the write doesn't somehow. I tried it with a txt file and it isn't writing anything to the file.

Comment: @DanieldeVogel probably because your file was empty and triggered EOF while reading. Try with `readsome` instead of `read`.

Comment: If I select a .mp4 file for example, it doesn't display any data. Why is this? Do I need to convert the byte data to a hex format for example?

Comment: Ah, if it's a binary file you first need to open it as a binary (`std::fstream s("test.mp4", std::ios_base::binary | std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::out`); and then print it with e.g. hex.

Comment: @DanieldeVogel I added an example with binary file as well.

Comment: Thank's for your reply! Since you added 'readsome' instead of 'read' it doesn't work anymore. Not on the binary file and not on a simple text file. If I change 'readsome' to 'read' in the text file version, it works. How to fix this?

Comment: @DanieldeVogel Well `readsome` is not ideal to say the least, I shouldn't have introduced it. Check the updated version with `read` and handling of EOF. Note that in practice you may need to handle a lot more cases, like insufficient rights, concurrent access, something else. It's just the basic one.